# Re-engineer Picasa video or googlevideo expiredate

Tags: picasa

I have question about Picasa video hot-link.

I want to know the user and album of this hot-link

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=0d1c6adced0061249&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1408976528&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=AE6DF966462FEB77DDDA5DAA29070BE058A6EF0B.8F0975B6794B082494472F0BE12730A7D61964A1&key=lh1
```

Because when I using this link it have an

```
expire=time
```

The video can't play when the time is up.

So I need to find the real of this video link.

But it seem the api doesn't have this feature ?

or am I missing some thing ?

Thanks you.